# Which Folder to File method compresses the most? zip vs tar.gz vs tar.bz2 vs tar

Tags: linux, unix, compression, zip, tar

I'm trying to download a large Gitlab repo in a script, and Gitlab offers each of the `zip`, `tar.gz`, `tar.bz2` and `tar` options, and I want to pick the one that will have the *smallest* file size.

Will one of these extensions/methods be guaranteed to be smaller than another?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1):

First of all; `tar` is not compressed by any means, it stores the raw files and related metadata (filenames, flags, checksums, ...).
You can pick one of a number of compressors to pipe the tar archive through though; see below.
As indicated by the name extensions, `tar.gz` has been piped through `gzip`, and `tar.bz2` through `bzip2`.

Expect the latest version of the compressors to be the most effective. The difference might not be impressively large in the end though.

The actual filed data and compressor settings used may make a larger difference.

```
$ zip --version
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
...

$ gzip --version
gzip 1.10
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...

$ bzip2 --version
bzip2, a block-sorting file compressor.  Version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019.
   
   Copyright (C) 1996-2019 by Julian Seward.
```

and then `tar`

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.30

...
$ tar --help
Usage: tar [OPTION...] [FILE]...
GNU 'tar' saves many files together into a single tape or disk archive, and can
restore individual files from the archive.

...

Compression options:

  -a, --auto-compress        use archive suffix to determine the compression
                             program
  -I, --use-compress-program=PROG
                             filter through PROG (must accept -d)
  -j, --bzip2                filter the archive through bzip2
  -J, --xz                   filter the archive through xz
      --lzip                 filter the archive through lzip
      --lzma                 filter the archive through xz
      --lzop                 filter the archive through lzop
      --no-auto-compress     do not use archive suffix to determine the
                             compression program
  -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip   filter the archive through gzip
      --zstd                 filter the archive through zstd
  -Z, --compress, --uncompress   filter the archive through compress
```